# Get Last row value and N row value before last row

Tags: php

How to read and echo the N rows before the last row in TEXT file using PHP?

Example in file.txt

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
```

I want to get the last row value and 3 row before last row.
So the result will be :

```
test4
test7
```

Here is my code so far (just show last row)

```
$line = '';
$f = fopen('\\\\192.168.183.28\\wk$\\sbin\\file.txt', 'r');
            $cursor = -1;

            fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
            $char = fgetc($f);

            while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
                fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
                $char = fgetc($f);
            }

            while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r")
            {
                $line = $char . $line;
                fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
                $char = fgetc($f);
            }

            $future_sn = substr($line, 28, 36);
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
// counting array and get key for prev
$prev_third = count($array)-4;
echo end($array); // test7
echo $array[$prev_third]; //test4
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use fgets() to read file and keep a counter to keep track of last row. You can get 3 row ahead from last by mod(%) the counter.

```
$handle = fopen("input.txt", "r");
$lastRow = "";
$last3Ahead = "";
$counter = 0;
$a = "";
$b = "";
$c = "";
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if($counter == 0) $a = $line;
    if($counter == 1) $b = $line;
    if($counter == 2) $c = $line;
    $lastRow = $line ;

    if($counter >= 3) {
      $last3Ahead  = $a;
      $a = $b;
      $b = $c;
      $c = $line
    } 
    $counter++;


 } else {
// error opening the file.
 } 
  fclose($handle);
  echo $lastRow. "<br>" ;     //last row
  echo $last3Ahead  . "<br>"; //3 row before last;
```

Comment: this answer won't work. your if logic for `last3ahead` is not going to do what you think it is.

Comment: sorry, i missed the !(not) operator, edited it should work now